# how to remove all text from Windows Command Line?

Tags: windows, command-line

**Problem :**

When writing long commands, sometimes I want to clear the line in one shot.

I know how to do it in Windows : Hold Shift, Home key, then delete. However this doesn't work in command prompt. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to clear the current command.